# Azure SQL Database elastic query on Azure SQL Database emulator

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-sharding

Is it possible to use [Azure SQL Database elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview) on an [Azure SQL Database emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/local-dev-experience-sql-database-emulator)?

I installed an Azure SQL Database emulator and followed the instructions in Elastic Query getting started [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical#external-data-sources) and during execute:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
        (TYPE = RDBMS,
        LOCATION = 'XXX',
        DATABASE_NAME = 'Customers',
        CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred
    ) ;
```

I get an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'RDBMS'.

Comment: I tried the same in my environment its working for me you can see here please check Syntax [here](https://i.imgur.com/2mvYYWu.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Azure SQL Database public service, some specific features may not be available. For example, the Azure SQL Database emulator does not support all features that are supported across multiple Azure SQL Database service tiers.

There is no limitation on the elastic query. Below query worke fine:

```sql
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE [DataSource2] WITH
(
TYPE  =  RDBMS,
LOCATION  =  'pdstackserver.database.windows.net',
DATABASE_NAME  =  'db1',
CREDENTIAL  = ElasticDBQueryCred1
)
```

[image]